# How to remotely access full file system on Android for backup?

Tags: external-sd, ftp

I have always used SFTP servers on my Android devices, with sync scripts run on my server daily to perform backups. I also transfer files to and from the devices this way.

With each version of Android, it becomes increasingly challenging. I now have a Samsung Tab7 FE with Android 11. I have spent hours buying and trying FTP servers, and none are working. Some only allow access to /storage/emulated/0, and the physical (external) sd-card is completely unavailable. After reading about [Storage Access Framework (SAF)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage), I found the [Primitive ftpd](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.primftpd/) from F-droid says it supports SAF, but it can only access new folders created by the Primitive sftpd app, and not the full file system.

What are workable approaches to provide filesystem access on Android over Wi-Fi, to enable unattended automatic backup and file transfer?

Edit - I am aware of ADB approaches, but as far as I know they are not unattended and automatic. I want to leave the tablet idle, connected to Wi-Fi, and have my script backup the tablet unattended at 2am.

Comment: Related: [How to backup apps and data on non-rooted Android without needing a PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218974/3573)

Comment: What OS are you running on your computer? Maybe ADB over WiFi in conjunction with [adbfs-rootless](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless) would be an option (I use that here, though via USB, to access my devices)?

Comment: there should be entry in developer options for legacy storage

Comment: What I don't understand if you're going to have unattended **full** backup it requires rooted device - therefore why bother with SAF? use your power of su https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245392